# Cannot call a router action from the view

Tags: ember.js

Here are my routes :

```
this.route('produits', function(){ 
  this.route('new');
  this.route('edit', { path: '/:produit_id/edit' }, function() {
    this.route('documents');
  });
});
```

Here is my action in routes/produit/edit/documents.js :

```
actions: {
    refreshRoute() {
      this.refresh();
    }   
}
```

In document.hbs as soon as I use `{{action refreshRoute}}`, it result in the following error: `Assertion Failed: An action named 'refreshRoute' was not found in (generated produits.edit.documents controller)`

Why is it not working, when using the same syntax works in CRUD views?

Comment: Add quotes around refreshRoute -`{{action  'refreshRoute'}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your action in your route. In order to reach route actions you can use [ember-route-action-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-route-action-helper). And instead of `{{action 'refreshRoute'}}`, you should use `{{route-action 'refreshRoute'}}` otherwise it will look for the action in the controller.